# You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to VueJS, I've got warning from Vue,

```
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

When i use V-for variable in V-bind:style, here is an example :
in template :

```
<div v-for="item in model.items" v-bind:class="test(item.result)">
{{item.id}}
</div>
```

in script :

```
data() {
    return {
        accept: false,
        not_accept: false,
    };
},
methods: {
    test(result) {
        if (result == 'accept') {
            this.accept = true;
            this.not_accept = false;
        } else if (result == 'Not accept') {
            this.accept = false;
            this.not_accept = true;
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }

        return {
            success: this.accept,
            danger: this.not_accept,
        };
    },
},
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

@Decade is right about the problem. Here is the exact problem:

1. You are in render method rendering the list of item using some state value

> NOTE: render method is triggered whenever any state changes

2. Then you are trying to bind the class based on a result of function `test` this function is flawed as it is again trying to mutate the state, thus causing the render - test - render cycle.

You can solve this problem by making your test function not mutate the state instead, like so:

```
methods: {
    test(result) {
        let accept;
        if (result == 'accept') {
            accept = true;
        } else if (result == 'Not accept') {
            accept = false;
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }

        return {
            success: accept,
            danger: !accept,
        };
    },
}
```

I hope that helped!

Comment: computed properties can't be called, and therefore can't have arguments. They are accessed like properties, so this code won't work.

Comment: @LinusBorg thanks for spotting the error, I didn't knew that. I fixed the example.

Comment: In my case I was passing an Object from state value to a new variable. What I did to get around this is to use spread operator, like so:

```
let obj = {};

// some conditions
obj  = {...objFromState}
```

Comment: just to add - under vuejs you can do similar as above no let or var is needed to declare the variable - a word of warning - if you attempt to assign it in a loop - as an example radio buttons current object becomes last row - I removed :`<span style="display:none;">
         <!-- this sets currentObject locally to be current stored results -->
        {{ currentObject = ( findFromArray(stored[0].facilities,'id',currentField.id).currentObject  )}}

      </span>` and called `findFromArray(stored[0].facilities,'id',currentField.id).currentObject  )` instead of variable name - all ok

Comment: so basically the op's fault was changing a data variable constantly in a method, so vue.js kept updating the render. i now created a let variable outside the export object and modified that for my needs. thanks for the hint, makes it clearer now.

Answer (score 34):

I was accidentally doing something similar and not that easy to spot with an untrained eye: calling `.sort()` on an array in a filter. `sort` mutates the array, thus making the component re-render. Solution is to first `slice` the array and create a shallow copy, then sort.

Bad:

```
 filters: {
    sortedDays(days) {
      return days.sort().join(', ');
    },
  },
```

Good:

```
 filters: {
    sortedDays(days) {
      return days.slice().sort().join(', ');
    },
  },
```

Comment: I think this good was making this mistake but performance wise then faster way would be `[...days].join(', ');`

Comment: If you were comparing the two, you forgot that there's a `sort` there. They are close, but slice comes first buy a bit: https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/14783/0/arrayprototypeslice-sort-vs-spread-operator-sort

Answer (score 14):

First, I'm not sure why you have `not_accept`, can't you just use `!this.accept` in its place?

I'm not 100% sure why you're getting this warning, but here's what I think.

The watcher for `v-bind:class` is watching for changes to `item.result`, `this.accept` and `this.not_accept`. Any change in those values will cause it to be re-rendered by calling `test` again. But within `test`, you're modifying `this.accept` and `this.not_accept`, so Vue needs to re-check again if the result has changed because of that, and in doing so it may change `this.accept` and `this.not_accept` *again*, and so on.

The `class` binding and the data is flawed. `class` for each of the items will be set to the same thing, but it looks as though you want a custom style for each item depending on `item.result`. You really shouldn't be modifying any properties of `this` inside `test`.

It's hard to give a thorough answer because I'm not completely sure of how your component works and what it should do.

Answer (score 8):

You can get this error if you call a function instead of pass a function in a vue directive.  Here is an example:

I made a custom [directive to load data via AJAX when a boostrap tab is displayed](https://gist.github.com/jesslilly/e6ccf70736bc1a8ae9abe5afc212c1de).

#### This is bad:

```
 v-on-show-bs-tab="getFirstPageSites()"
```

Here, vue appears to call the function (or rather evaluate the expression) and pass the result to the directive.

#### This is good:

```
 v-on-show-bs-tab="getFirstPageSites"
```

Here I am passing the function by name such that I can call it in the directive.

Comment: Doesn't really apply to the OP's question.  How are you passing the current item data to the function?

Comment: @Mike I found this question on Google by searching for the error message.  This is why I got the error message and the fix that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error after making the dumb mistake of using `:click` in a component instead of `@click`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was mutating an object inside a function, and I think that whenever I mutated it, it called the same function again and again (kind of a recursion). So instead of have this in the function body:

```
this.someProperty = myObject;
```

I put all the code in a new function (the function's name is `totalesSimples`) that return "myObject".

And in the HTML part, instead of showing it like:

```
{{someProperty}}
```

I showed it with:

```
{{totalesSimples()}}
```

This way, I was not mutating a property inside a function and showing it; I was showing the function's result.

Answer (score 0):

What I did wrong:

I didn't use an arrow function when using data

For example:

```
data() {
  state: {
     foo: 'bar'
  }
},
created() {
  bus.$on('data_change', function(data) {
    this.state = Object.assign({}, this.state, data); <-- this will cause an infinite loop
  });
}
```

Used an arrow function instead:

```
created() {
  bus.$on('data_change',(data) => {
    this.state = Object.assign({}, this.state, data);
  });
}
```

Thought it looked like a common mistake

Comment: does your solution work with the arrow function because `this.state` is automatically being returned or due to some other reason? @glinda93

Comment: @MCGRAW arrow function does not change `this` scope, while traditional function changes `this` scope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions