# infinite update loop in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to write a custom component. And hope I can use it like this

```
let app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    template:`
    <tab>
    <tab-item name='1'>
    <h1> This is tab item 1</h1>
    </tab-item>
    <tab-item name='2'>
    <h2> This is tab item 2</h2>
    </tab-item>
    </tab>`,
    components:{
        tab,
        tabItem
    }
})
```

Everything goes fine until you click the button. I got an error from console:

```
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

found in

---> <Tab>
       <Root>
```

I've tried many ways to solve this problem, however, failure always won the debugging competition.

How can I beat this problem?

Here is my code:

```
let tabItem = {
    props:{
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    render(h){
        let head = this.$slots.head || ''
        let body = this.$slots.default
        let tail = this.$slots.tail || ''
        return h('div', [ 
            h('div', head),
            h('div', body),
            h('div', tail)])
    }
}

let tab = {

    data(){
        return {
            items:'',
            currentView:0
        }
    },
    methods:{
        handleTabClick(item){
            return ()=>{
                let index = this.items.indexOf(item)
                this.currentView = this.items[index]
            }
        },
        extractProps(vnode){
            return vnode.componentOptions.propsData
        }
    },
    render(h){
        this.items = this.$slots.default.filter( node => {
            return /tab-item/.test(node.tag)
        })
        let headers = this.items.map( item => {
            let name = this.extractProps(item).name
            return h('button', {
                on:{
                    click: this.handleTabClick(item)
                }
            }, name)
        })
        let head = h('div', headers)
        this.currentView = this.items[0]
        return h('div',[head, this.currentView])
    }
}
```

Or any other ways to implement this component?

Thanks a lot for helping me out from the hell.

Thanks for your reply my friends. I'm pretty sure that I get an infinite loop error from the console and my code doesn't work as expected. I don't think using `vnode` is a good way to implement this component too. However, this is the best solution I can figure out.

This component -- `tab` should detect its child whose name is `tabItem`, which is also a component. And `tab` can extract some data from `tabItem`. In my case, `tab` will extract the `name` property of `tabItemn`, which will be used to generate the buttons for switching content. Click the button can switch to the relevant content, which is the body of `tabItem`. In my code, it's `currenView`.

Like a famous UI library, [Element](http://element-cn.eleme.io/#/en-US),  its `tab` component can be used like this:

```
<el-tabs v-model="activeName" @tab-click="handleClick">
  <el-tab-pane label="User" name="first">User</el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane label="Config" name="second">Config</el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane label="Role" name="third">Role</el-tab-pane>
  <el-tab-pane label="Task" name="fourth">Task</el-tab-pane>
</el-tabs>
```

I need to implement one component like this but mine will be more simple. For learning how to do it, I read its source code. Maybe there's not a good way to filter child components. In the source, they use this to filter the `el-tab-pane` component:

```
  addPanes(item) {
    const index = this.$slots.default.filter(item => {
      return item.elm.nodeType === 1 && /\bel-tab-pane\b/.test(item.elm.className);
    }).indexOf(item.$vnode);
    this.panes.splice(index, 0, item);
  }
```

[Source Code](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/packages/tabs/src/tabs.vue)

I know that I can use `$children` to access its child components but doing so doesn't guarantee the order of the child components, which is not what I want. Because the order of switching button is important. Detail messages about `vnode` are not contained in the doc. I need to read the source.

Therefore, after reading the source of Vue, I wrote my code like this then I got my problem.

I finally didn't solve this bug and admit that using this kind of rare code sucks. But I don't know other solutions. So I need you guys help.

Thanks.

Comment: For sure you have an infinite loop. Your render function always calls itself. What are you trying to do, and why do you need slots, vnode and hand-rolled render functions (which are exotic, potentially complicated and rarely used) ?

Comment: @bbsimonbb yeah, I also think this sucks, but I can't find another way to do it.. I add more information.

Answer (score 6):

[You shouldn't change your data in render function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153274/4738332), this is wrong

```
this.items = this.$slots.default.filter( node => {
  return /tab-item/.test(node.tag)
})
```

because it will keep re-rendering, here is a working example for your code, I simply removed `items` property from data and added new `items` computed property which returns `tab-item`s nodes.

```js
let tab = {

    data(){
        return {
            currentView:0
        }
    },
    methods:{
        handleTabClick(item){
            return ()=>{
                let index = this.items.indexOf(item)
                this.currentView = this.items[index]
            }
        },
        extractProps(vnode){
            return vnode.componentOptions.propsData

        }
    },
    computed: {
     items(){
       return this.$slots.default.filter( node => {
            return /tab-item/.test(node.tag)
        })
      }
    },
    render(h){
        
        let headers = this.items.map( item => {
            let name = this.extractProps(item).name
            return h('button', {
                on:{
                    click: this.handleTabClick(item)
                }
            }, name)
        })
        
        
        let head = h('div', headers)
        
        this.currentView = this.items[0]
        
        return h('div',[head, this.currentView])
    }
}

let tabItem = {
  name:"tab-item",
    props:{
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    render(h){
        let head = this.$slots.head || ''
        let body = this.$slots.default
        let tail = this.$slots.tail || ''
        return h('div', [[ 
            h('div', head),
            h('div', body),
            h('div', tail)]])
    }
}


let app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    template:`
    <tab>
    <tab-item name='1'>
    <h1> This is tab item 1</h1>
    </tab-item>
    <tab-item name='2'>
    <h2> This is tab item 2</h2>
    </tab-item>
    </tab>`,
    components:{
        tab,
        tabItem
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>  

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Your solution did stop the warning from console. However, it can't run as expected. When click the button, content didn't switch. But you find the key to solve it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: as for changing content when clicking the buttons, you need to change `this.currentView = this.items[0]` line, change the index to select the needed content dynamically,