# VueJS update variable in loop

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to get the "last new date" for a conversation components, but when I update my `temp_date` to compare with `message.date` I have a "infinite update loop".

I've find this topic [You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151265/you-may-have-an-infinite-update-loop-in-a-component-render-function)
But I don't know how to apply it on my case...

I've made a fiddle, is it the right way ? Any best pratice about that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/odgj7wu5/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your template like this

```html
<div v-for="message in uniqueMessages" :key="message.id">
```

and define the computed property `uniqueMessages` like this

```js
computed:
{
   uniqueMessages()
   {
     return this.messages.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
   }
}
```

you won't need the `showDate` function.

Comment: But I won't get all messages right ?
I want to get all messages but unique date.

Comment: You will get only the first message (the one appearing earlier inside the array) for each date - you may need to sort your array so that the latest message for a given day comes before the older ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used an other formatted array like this:

```
mounted() {
    let dates: string[];
    dates = this.messages.map( message => message.date);
    const uniq_dates = [...new Set(dates)];
    for (const date of uniq_dates) {
        this.ordered_messages.push({
            date: date,
            messages: this.messages.filter(message => date == message.date)
        });
    }
}
```