# saldo counter in vue for loop gives infinite loop error

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**(There's a PD)**

I have a page where I show account movements.
In the DB there is the date and the amount.
A separate table holds a saldo for beginning of each month.
Aditionally the table is filtrable by start and end date

The filtered entries from the bank account movements have a date and an amount and this is working fine.
I am trying now to fusion that with the account-saldo.
The start is easy: take and show startSaldo from DB

On render side I have a v-for loop going though each movement
strange is I am getting an infinite loop on an unexpected method

Rendering:

```
<tr v-for="movimiento in this.filteredEntries">
                ...

                <td>{{calculateSaldo(movimiento.cobro_id,movimiento.monto)}}</td>
                ...
</tr>
```

saldo is a simple property (not a calculated one), at the moment initiated with 0 and only used within the method

and this is the method

```
calculateSaldo(cobro_id,monto){
            //cobro_id and monto are 
            return 0; // <<<< without this I get the infinite loop error. But why?
            if (cobro_id){
                this.saldo=this.saldo+parseInt(monto);
            } else {
                this.saldo= this.saldo-parseInt(monto);
            }
            console.log(this.saldo);
            // <<< a return 0 here produces also an infinite loop error
            return this.saldo;
        },
```

I have no clue where to futher look...

**PD: After some more tests, apparently as soon as I reassign a value to this.saldo a re-render is initiated. How overcome that?**

**PPD: Apparently the re-render happens after reaching the last (by Date) filtered Entity**

Comment: When your each reassign a value in state, in your example `this.saldo` render triggered. Can you please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153274/1977031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153274/1977031) when you reassign a value in state render triggered and it causes an infinite loop.

So I tried to recreate a basic version of your component and I think you can solve this on your `filteredEntries` computed property.

```
computed: {
    filteredEntries() {
      let lastSaldo = this.saldo;
      return this.entries.map((item) => {
        if (item.cobro_id) {
          lastSaldo = parseInt(lastSaldo) + parseInt(item.monto);
        } else {
          lastSaldo = parseInt(lastSaldo) - parseInt(item.monto);
        }
        item.saldo = lastSaldo;
        return item;
      });
    },
  },
```

Complete code of my recreation of your component example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr v-for="(movimiento, index) in this.filteredEntries" :key="index">
        <td>{{ movimiento.saldo }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      saldo: 0,
      entries: [
        {
          cobro_id: null,
          monto: 5,
        },
        {
          cobro_id: 2,
          monto: 10,
        },
        {
          cobro_id: null,
          monto: 5,
        },
        {
          cobro_id: 1,
          monto: 25,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredEntries() {
      let lastSaldo = this.saldo;
      return this.entries.map((item) => {
        if (item.cobro_id) {
          lastSaldo = parseInt(lastSaldo) + parseInt(item.monto);
        } else {
          lastSaldo = parseInt(lastSaldo) - parseInt(item.monto);
        }
        item.saldo = lastSaldo;
        return item;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It seemed to work perfectly.. until I programmed that let saldo = getSaldo(startDate)  
As it is a vue component that filters the entries based on selectable dates, whenever a date is changed, the entities are filtred and a new Saldo must be taken from DB. 
it seems that the delay in the axios call provokes that lastSaldo is undefined.
Any idea on how to implememt that the return entries is triggered after the axios Call gets his answer? do I eventually need to split this vue component into two parts? One for the dates and a child component only to deal with the entries?