# You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function vue js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Im using method to hide or show " In stock " label
this's my HTML :

```
<span class="stock" v-if="inStock(variance)">{{$t('in_stock')}}</span>
```

and the method

```
inStock(variance){
        variance.quantity.forEach((q)=>{
            if(q.location_id == this.defaultWarehouseID){
                this.defaultQuantity = q.quantity
            }
        }
        )
        if(this.defaultQuantity > 0) return true
        else return false
```

and I'm getting this error :- **You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function**

**NOTE :-** I know this error because I'm using reactive data while rendering , but I don't know how to use block scoped variable with the arrow function inside forEach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151265/you-may-have-an-infinite-update-loop-in-a-component-render-function)

Comment: @FUZIION i know that the solution is to declare block scoped variable , but i don't know how to apply it in my case , because the arrow function that im using inside the foreach cannot see this variable

Comment: Do not mutate "this.defaultQuantity" and use a local variable as in the post/solution provided from FUZZION. E.g: `let quantity = this.defaultQuantity`  before your foreach loop, and inside it `quantity = q.quantity` instead of `this.defaultQuantity = q.quantity`