# [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function - cannot see why

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, buefy

I have a method in Vue to take an array of tags and sets it to an array value in an object. I've been having problems with the error suggesting an infinite loop. When a tag is input, it should call the addData method.

I came across this question with the same error ([You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151265/you-may-have-an-infinite-update-loop-in-a-component-render-function)), and have been trying to make sure the method does not cause the component to re-render by creating a new array and using the Vue.set function. I am still getting the infinite loop error and I have not idea why after much head banging.

To add to my confusion, I print out the data, and when I add the tags they add to the data as expected, not an infinite amount of times.

The relevant code:

In the html template:

```
<div class="columns is-vcentered is-centered" v-if="true">
    <b-field label="Preferences (leave empty for any)">
        <b-taginput 
            maxtags="5"
            maxlength="20"
            placeholder="eg: Aldi"
            v-model="tags['supermarket']"
            :create-tag="addData('supermarket')">
        </b-taginput>
    </b-field>
</div>
```

In the script:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            tags: {
                supermarket: []
            },
            data: {
                supermarket: {
                    isSelected: false,
                    amenity: "supermarket",
                    preferences: []
            }

        }
    },
    methods: {
        addData(amenityName) {
            let prefs = [];
            for (let t in this.tags[amenityName]){
                prefs.push({
                    amenity: this.tags[amenityName][t]
                });
            };
            this.$set(this.data[amenityName], "preferences", prefs); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know Vue.js but in many frameworks this is caused by an infinite loop between rerendering the view and updating the state. Here addData updates the reference of preferences, at the same time the view seems to be updated on preferences change and ALSO seems to call addData during the rendering (which might trigger a new rendering due to preferences being changed again). A solution might be to only update preferences reference (that's to say set a new prefs array) if there were actual changes in the preferences

Comment: I don't think you're using `create-tag` correctly. The purpose of that function is to transform whatever is entered into the tag you want. Eg [the default](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/dev/src/components/taginput/Taginput.vue#L185) is `(tag) => tag`

Comment: Agh, yes, the problem was trying to put the custom function in create-tag. I was trying to call this function whenever a new tag was added. Instead I will try using a watch. Thank you both!